# Cargar Servicio antes que un componente(angular)

Tags: javascript, angular

Estoy tratando de mostrar un componente en función de un dato. Este dato se recoge de un servicio que llama a la DDBB. El problema es que al recargar el navegador, el dato vuela del servicio y tengo que volver a hacer la llamada al recargar el componente con el problema añadido de que el componente se cargar antes que el servicio:

-Propiedad en servicio => 1
-Reload webpage => propiedad undifined

-componente A => Llama al servicio de nuevo/ El dato llega después de la construcción del componente

- Resultado => El componente no se muestra

alguna orientación?

Gracias!!

Comment: Añade el código del componente y del servicio, es complicado encontrar una solución sin saber qué estás realmente queriendo hacer

Comment: Si añades un servicio al constructor, éste se construye antes de que el componente se cargue. Ahora bien. lo que estás intentando hacer es una llamada asíncrona a un servidor remoto con lo que debes usar algún sistema de programación asíncrona para manejar esto. Angular te permite usar RxJS, Promesas, async-await y los métodos fetch de las versiones más recientes de ECMA. Elige el que te sea más cómodo y si necesitas más ayuda pon el código como dijo Pablo y comenta qué probaste.

Comment: quizas debas utilizar Resolver, para solucionar tu problema, te paso un link, [Curso de Angular de gavilanch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H_YeAM1y0Zo&t=26s),